# Solr 8.2.0 fails to startup in cloud mode

Tags: solr, lucene

Failed to run Solr-8.2.0 in cloud mode.

Downloaded solr-8.2.0.tgz from the site and extracted it in the directory solr-8.2.0. The followed the instruction from the following link -
https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/solr-tutorial.html

I ran the following command:

```
./solr start -e cloud
```

But keep getting the following error -

> ERROR: Failed to start Solr using command: "<path to>/solr-8.2.0/bin/solr" start -cloud -p 8983 -s "<path to>/solr-8.2.0/example/cloud/node1/solr" Exception : org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)

I expect Solr to run in cloud mode i.e. on ports 8983 and 7574. But this does not happen!

PS - I did manage to start successfully in the cloud mode 5 days ago though.

Comment: Can you also provide what messages are reported in the Solr log file (e.g. server/logs/solr.log) ?

Comment: @Shubhangi. Just started the Server in cloud mode to fetch the logs and it is working like a charm. Though confused what could be reason yesterday. Anyway, many thanks for your help and my apologies to have wasted your time!

Comment: reported error could come due to various reasons such - open file limit, number of running process limit , permission, port binding etc. During restart, env might have been cleared up.

Comment: Thanks Shubhangi. You are correct. I have to put -force option to make it work.

Comment: Found the same issue in 8.3.1.